# SQL Select the most recent record for each ID

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, the first one is like this:

```
     INTERNSHIP
ID|  Term
---------
1 | 2015
1 | 2014
2 | 2016
2 | 2017
```

The second one is like this:

```
       Term
Term| Term Description | End Date
---------------------------------
2014 |  Summer 2014   | 8/12014
2014 |  Summer 2014   | 8/12014
2015 |  Fall 2015     | 12/1/2015
2017 |  Spring 2017   | 4/1/2017
2017 |  Spring 2017   | 6/1/2017
```

I need to find the "Term Description" for the most recent term for all the IDs. The desired result is like this:

```
ID| Term | Term Description 
------------------
1 |  2015   |  Fall 2015   
2 |  2017   |  Spring 2017
```

I did some research and came up with a solution like this:

```
SELECT INTERNSHIP.ID, INTERNSHIP.Term
FROM INTERNSHIP
WHERE (
  SELECT MAX(INTERNSHIP.Term)
  )
GROUP BY INTERNSHIP.ID
```

By that I got the distinct IDs with the most recent term, but I could not JOIN that with the Term Description. Can someone help me to get the desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**

```
SELECT i.id, i.term, t.Term_Description
FROM INTERNSHIP i
INNER JOIN Term t ON t.Term = i.term
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(t.End_Date) End_Date
            FROM INTERNSHIP i
            INNER JOIN Term t ON t.Term = i.term
            GROUP BY i.ID) t1 ON t1.End_Date = t.End_Date
```

Answer (score 4):

Does your SQL version allow you to use window functions?

If so, you can solve it easily like this :

```
SELECT C.ID,C.Term,C.Term_Description
FROM(
SELECT A.ID,A.TERM,B.Term_Description,Max(A.Term) OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID) AS Most_Recent_Year
FROM INTERNSHIP A INNER JOIN TERM B ON A.Term = B.Term
)C
WHERE C.Term = C.Most_Recent_Year
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT i.id, i.term, t.Term_Description
FROM (SELECT i.id, MAX(i.Term) as term
      FROM INTERNSHIP i
      GROUP BY i.id
     ) i JOIN
     Term t
     ON t.Term = i.term;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH internships AS (
    SELECT i.id, [term] = MAX(i.term) FROM Internship i GROUP BY i.id
), terms AS (SELECT t.term, [endDate] = MAX(t.endDate) FROM Term t GROUP BY t.term)
SELECT internships.id, internships.term, t.term_Description
FROM internships
    JOIN terms ON internships.term = terms.term
    JOIN Term t ON terms.term = t.term AND terms.endDate = t.endDate
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).